# ignore text size slider from settings in application

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-size

Is there a way to ignore the text size slider in the settings of an iOS device in your application?  Increasing this to large values can cause display issues in my app.

Comment: Your users wouldn't be happy with your app if you did this. As someone on the verge of needing reading glasses, I appreciate apps that properly honor the text size I set in the Settings app.

Comment: Its been requested by a client.  I dont really have a choice lol